# Errors and failures in Scala Parser Combinators

Tags: parsing, scala, parser-combinators

I would like to implement a parser for some defined language using Scala Parser Combinators. However, the software that will compile the language does not implements all the language's feature, so I would like to fail if these features are used. I tried to forge a small example below :

```
object TestFail extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def test: Parser[String] =
    "hello" ~ "world" ^^ { case _ => ??? } |
    "hello" ~ ident ^^ { case "hello" ~ id => s"hi, $id" }
}
```

I.e., the parser succeeds on "hello" + some identifier, but fails if the identifier is "world". I see that there exist fail() and err() parsers in the Parsers class, but I cannot figure out how to use them, as they return Parser[Nothing] instead of a String. The documentation does not seem to cover this use case…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you want `err`, not `failure`, since if the first parser in a disjunction fails you'll just move on to the second, which isn't what you want.

The other issue is that `^^` is the equivalent of `map`, but you want `flatMap`, since `err("whatever")` is a `Parser[Nothing]`, not a `Nothing`. You could use the `flatMap` method on `Parser`, but in this context it's more idiomatic to use the (completely equivalent) `>>` operator:

```
object TestFail extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def test: Parser[String] =
    "hello" ~> "world" >> (x => err(s"Can't say hello to the $x!")) |
    "hello" ~ ident ^^ { case "hello" ~ id => s"hi, $id" }
}
```

Or, a little more simply:

```
object TestFail extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def test: Parser[String] =
    "hello" ~ "world" ~> err(s"Can't say hello to the world!") |
    "hello" ~ ident ^^ { case "hello" ~ id => s"hi, $id" }
}
```

Either approach should do what you want.

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. Are the >>, ~> (and <~) operators documented somewhere (outside of the Scaladoc which was not detailed enough for me) ?

Comment: @scand1sk: See [`Parsers#Parser`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser) class for documentation.

Comment: I guess `"hello" ~ "world" >>` is a typo, there should be `"hello" ~> "world" >>` to use `$x`.

Comment: @senia: Thanks—you're right, my original version will compile and work but the error message won't be as clear as it should be.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `^?` method:

```
object TestFail extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def test: Parser[String] =
    "hello" ~> ident ^? (
      { case id if id != "world" => s"hi, $id" },
      s => s"Should not use '$s' here."
  )
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution would be too much cumbersome in my global parser project…

Comment: @scand1sk: `>>` is the best solution in your case. But `^?` allows you to use an addition method like this: `case _ ~ id if isValidId(id) =>`.