# Using `err` in a Child Parser

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

In the following Parser:

```
object Foo extends JavaTokenParsers { 

  def word(x: String) = s"\\b$x\\b".r

  lazy val expr  = aSentence | something

  lazy val aSentence = noun ~ verb ~ obj

  lazy val noun   = word("noun")
  lazy val verb   = word("verb") | err("not a verb!")
  lazy val obj    = word("object")

  lazy val something = word("FOO")
}
```

It will parse `noun verb object`.

```
scala> Foo.parseAll(Foo.expr, "noun verb object")
res1: Foo.ParseResult[java.io.Serializable] = [1.17] parsed: ((noun~verb)~object)
```

But, when entering a valid `noun`, but an invalid `verb`, why won't the `err("not a verb!")` return an [Error](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Error) with that particular error message?

```
scala> Foo.parseAll(Foo.expr, "noun vedsfasdf")
res2: Foo.ParseResult[java.io.Serializable] =
[1.6] failure: string matching regex `\bverb\b' expected but `v' found

noun vedsfasdf
     ^
```

**credit**: Thanks to [Travis Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334519/travis-brown) for explaining the need for the `word` function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24746501/409976).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17448577/409976) seems similar, but I'm not sure how to handle `err` with the `~` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another question you might ask: why isn't it complaining that it expected the word "FOO" but got "noun"? After all, if it fails to parse `aSentence`, it's then going to try `something`.

The culprit should be obvious when you think about it: what in that source code is taking two `Failure` results and choosing one? `|` (aka `append`).

This method on `Parser` will feed the input to both parsers, and then call `append` on `ParseResult`. That method is abstract at that level, and defined on `Success`, `Failure` and `Error` in different ways.

On both `Success` and `Error`, it always take `this` (that is, the parser on the left). On `Failure`, though, it does something else:

```
case class Failure(override val msg: String, override val next: Input) extends NoSuccess(msg, next) {
  /** The toString method of a Failure yields an error message. */
  override def toString = "["+next.pos+"] failure: "+msg+"\n\n"+next.pos.longString

  def append[U >: Nothing](a: => ParseResult[U]): ParseResult[U] = { val alt = a; alt match {
    case Success(_, _) => alt
    case ns: NoSuccess => if (alt.next.pos < next.pos) this else alt
  }}
}
```

Or, in other words, if both sides have failed, then it will take the side that read the most of the input (which is why it won't complain about a missing `FOO`), but if both have read the same amount, it will give precedence to the *second* failure.

I do wonder if it shouldn't check whether the *right* side is an `Error`, and, if so, return that. After all, if the *left* side is an `Error`, it always return that. This look suspicious to me, but maybe it's supposed to be that way. But I digress.

Back to the problem, it would seem that it should have gone with `err`, as they both consumed the same amount of input, right? Well... Here's the thing: regex parsers skip whiteSpace first, but that's for *regex* literals and literal strings. It does not apply over all other methods, including `err`.

That means that `err`'s input is at the whitespace, while the word's input is at the word, and, therefore, further on the input. Try this:

```
lazy val verb   = word("verb") | " *".r ~ err("not a verb!")
```

Arguably, `err` ought to be overridden by `RegexParsers` to do the right thing (tm). Since Scala Parser Combinators is now a separate project, I suggest you open an issue and follow it up with a Pull Request implementing the change. It will have the impact of changing error messages for some parser (well, that's the whole purpose of changing it :).

Comment: re: `why isn't it complaining that it expected the word "FOO" but got "noun"`: as I understand `Error`, there's no back-tracking allowed. Whereas, a `Failure` allows back-tracking. So, wrt to your question, I would not expect the behavior you proposed/mentioned.

Comment: Looks like that change got implemented for `err` to consume whitespace - https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators/commit/dc9e9cf67bb459d3e7fd0969054f837846461036